# Converter Json em um Objeto Csharp

Tags: c#, json, objetos

```
 public IActionResult MoedaTurismo()
    {
        try
        {
            RestClient restClient = new RestClient();
            RestRequest restRequest = new RestRequest();
            restRequest.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
            restRequest.AddHeader("content-Type", "application/json");
            restClient.BaseUrl = new Uri("http://economia.awesomeapi.com.br/USD-BRLT/1");

            var response = restClient.Execute(restRequest);

            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                var json = response.Content;
                var Moeda = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

                return (object);
            }
            return NotFound();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return StatusCode((int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);

        }

    }
```

Quero converter Json para C#, esta correto ?

Comment: Em teoria sim, qual o erro?

Comment: preciso fazer a conversão Json para objeto c#.

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro use [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/) para mapear todos os campos do Json para uma classe.

Modelo:

```
public class Moeda
{
  public string code { get; set; }
  public string codein { get; set; }
  public string name { get; set; }
  public string high { get; set; }
  public string low { get; set; }
  public string pctChange { get; set; }
  public string open { get; set; }
  public string bid { get; set; }
  public string ask { get; set; }
  public string varBid { get; set; }
  public string timestamp { get; set; }
  public string create_date { get; set; }
}
```

JSON:

```
[  
   {  
      "code":"USD",
      "codein":"BRLT",
      "name":"D\u00f3lar Turismo",
      "high":"3.91",
      "low":"3.75",
      "pctChange":"-0.488",
      "open":"0",
      "bid":"3.76",
      "ask":"4.08",
      "varBid":"-0.02",
      "timestamp":"1544452500000",
      "create_date":"2018-12-10 12:40:03"
   }
]
```

Note que o JSON trazido na url ele é composto por `[]` então ele é interpretado como uma matriz e não um objeto, então use uma coleção para deserializar JSON  [`List<T>`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Exemplo:

```
 public IActionResult MoedaTurismo()
 {
            try
            {
                RestClient restClient = new RestClient();
                RestRequest restRequest = new RestRequest();
                restRequest.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
                restRequest.AddHeader("content-Type", "application/json");
                restClient.BaseUrl = new Uri("http://economia.awesomeapi.com.br/USD-BRLT/1");

                var response = restClient.Execute(restRequest);

                if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    var json = response.Content;
                    List<Moeda> obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Moeda>>(json);

                    return (object);
                }
                return NotFound();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return StatusCode((int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);

            }

 }
```